# Network problem beetwen two containers in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have four containers. A container for the php server, a container for the mysql server, a container for ngnix and a container for let's encrypt.

The problem is that the php server can't connect to the mysql server.

In the server, I can connect to the database on 127.0.0.1

[Schema update in the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQjTx.png)

In the container, I can't connect to the database on 127.0.0.1

[Schema update in php container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfRax.png)

I think it's a problem of network beetwen the containers.

This is the docker-compose :

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  saas-smd-php:
    build: ./html
    container_name: saas-smd-php
    ports:
      - "80"
    network_mode: bridge
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=80

  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - dhparam:/etc/nginx/dhparam
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    network_mode: bridge

  letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    container_name: nginx-proxy-le
    environment:
      - NGINX_PROXY_CONTAINER=nginx-proxy
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - dhparam:/etc/nginx/dhparam
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    network_mode: bridge

  db:
    container_name: saas-smd-mysql
    image: mysql
    ports:
    - "3306:3306"
    env_file:
    - .env
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/mysql
    network_mode: bridge
volumes:
  data:
  conf:
  vhost:
  html:
  dhparam:
  certs:
```

And the Dockerfile of the php server :

```
ARG PHP_VERSION=7.3

FROM php:${PHP_VERSION}-fpm-alpine

RUN apk update
RUN apk upgrade

RUN set -ex \
    && apk --no-cache add postgresql-libs postgresql-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install pgsql pdo_pgsql \
    && apk del postgresql-dev

WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY saas-api .

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 22

CMD ["php", "-S", "0.0.0.0:80", "-t", "./", "./web/app_dev.php"]
```

I would like to the php server can communicate with the mysql server, without breaking the access of the php server from a domain name with ngnix and let's encrypt.

Comment: try to connect using docker service names not `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not provide any info on how you connect, I will go ahead and assume you are just not using you database container name; and you're supposed to use `saas-smd-mysql` instead of `localhost`.